# Handle left right trackball swipe in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, navigation, trackball

How do I write code to handle event that are fired when the track ball in a black berry app is swiped left and right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`navigationMovement`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#navigationMovement%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method of the selected field is called when such an event occurs. You can override it an place your logic there. The first parameter helps you determine what kind of movement it is(left/right) :

> dx - Magnitude of navigational motion:
>   negative for a move left and postive
>   for a move right.